# Dependent autocomplete script

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to use autocomplete script but I have this problem

```
public function searchconcli(Request $request) {

    $query = $request->get('term', '');
    $cli_id = $request->get('id_cli', '');


    $countries = \DB::table('contactoscli')->where('cli_id', $cli_id);

    if ($request->type == 'cliente') {

        $countries->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');

    }
```

Seems like Variable $cli_id are empty because if I set value manualy:

```
$cli_id = '4329';
```

The script works good and only show result with this cli_id

I send value of name with javascript script but I not found how I can take value of id_cli and send with ajax.

This javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//autocomplete script clientes
$(document).on('focus', '.autocompleteconcli_txt', function () {

    type = $(this).data('type');
    id_cli = document.getElementById("id_cli_1").value//obtener valor del
    if (type == 'cliente')
        autoType = 'name';

    $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchajaxconcli') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    type: type,
                    id_cli: request.id_cli,
                    type: type,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item[autoType],
                            value: item[autoType],
                            data: item
                        }
                    });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0,
        appendTo: "#crearviaje",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var data = ui.item.data;
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            elementId = id[id.length - 1];
            $('#tel_con_cli').val(data.telefone);
            $('#name_con_cli').val(data.name);
            $('#mail_con_cli').val(data.mail);
            $('#id_con_cli').val(data.id);
        }
    });
});
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: `id_cli: request.id_cli` should be `id_cli: id_cli`.

Comment: @ljubadr perfect!!! thanks so much

Comment: I'm gald it worked. Use browser devtools, network panel to inspect what's sent to server. It would be easy to spot that it's missing or that value is not properly set.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax requests data object is missing `id_cli`:

```
data: {
    id_cli: ???,
    term: request.term,
    type: type,
 }
```

Comment: I add data object id_cli . I edit script and function but steel don't work. I'm not sure where is the problem